# PSBoundParameters in PowerShell 5 Class

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Is it possible to splat or use $PSBoundParameters in a PowerShell 5 class? For example, I want to do this:

```
class foo {
  [void]baz($i) {
  }

  [void]bar($i) {
  $this.baz(@PSBoundParameters)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested whether it works first?  I don't see a reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: It doesn't compile

Comment: Well, it's a script with an interpreter so that's natural.

Comment: no, powershell 5 classes get compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed, it seems to not be possible.